# Probability of difference between any two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given random variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ which are **i.i.d.** with $x_i \sim \mathcal N(\eta, \sigma^2), \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$.

I tried to find the probability that none of these random variables are separated by a value less than $d$ such that

$$\Pr(x_k-x_m \geq d)$$

for any $k$    and $m \in [1,n]$. I have looked for some questions here in    Stackexchange for finding the difference between two random variables    $X$ and $Y$ but I don't know how that scale for a set of $n$ random variables so as $n$ increases the above probability will decrease.

I am asking for guidance here to solve it.

Comment: In other words, you want $P(|x_i-x_j|>d:\forall i,j)$, as a function of $d$?

Comment: Thanks Nash J. for the edit.

Comment: Yes kimchi lover that's right. To find how d can affect the probability.

Comment: There is probably no useful exact expression for the distribution of $\min_{i,j}|x_i-x_j|$, so you will have to content yourself with approximations.  Are we to assume $n$ is large, and $d$ small?